# Eclipse, GWT plugin. Debugger does't work

Tags: eclipse, gwt

```
Ubuntu 10.10
SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.5.0.M3 Build Id: 201008251000
```

When I try to debug, Debug As-> web Application, the tab with Source not found opens. With stack trace in debug mode:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 202 [local variables unavailable]  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 190 
Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 229 
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 307   
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 296   
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 301    
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 248    
InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(String, String, String) line: 280    
InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(String, String) line: 338
```

In the Development Mode tab is text with Development mode is loading, where should be web app URL provided... So what is going on?

Comment: Coould you resume the application after this exception?

Answer (score 3):

This was eclipse bug. `ClassNotFoundException: caught and uncaught` breakpoint was set by unknown reason.. So it should be deleted from 'Breakpoints' window/tab.

More details here: http://www.popcornfarmer.com/gamedev/2009/01/eclipse-debug-error/