# Java: Eclipse ClassNotFound exception when constructing matrix of objects

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, classnotfoundexception

I'm implementing a quadruple-linked list in Java as a matrix of Node objects, which I've implemented as an inner class:

```
public class Test {

    private Node[][] Matrix;

    class Node {
        int data; 
        Node up;
        Node down;
        Node left;
        Node right;
    }

    public Test() {
        Matrix = new Node[10][10];
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                Matrix[row][col] = new Node();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

}
```

First of all, is this the right/best way to do it?  Second, although it runs fine, when I debug line-by-line I get the error `Test(Object).<init>() line: 37 [local variables unavailable]` and also a `Source not found` window just before I would advance to the line `Matrix = new Node[10][10];`. It then gets stuck at that line and gives me a ClassNotFound exception:

```
owns: Object  (id=28)   
owns: Object  (id=29)   
ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286   
ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available 
ClassNotFoundException(ReflectiveOperationException).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available  
ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available   
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: That stacktrace indicates you're trying to load a class over the network... is this running as an applet?  Does that stacktrace go with this code?

Comment: @JimGarrison It's running as a Java Application, and the stacktrace definitely goes with the code, I did it again and got the same thing.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (Eclipse Juno, Java 1.6).  I'd suggest making sure you have a recent Eclipse (i.e. Indigo or Juno) and Java (>=1.6).

Comment: @JimGarrison I have JRE 1.7 and Juno Eclipse, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further thought, I don't think this is actually a bug.  It's using the default constructor for Object, the source code for which Eclipse might very well not have access to (since it's part of the Java library or whatever).  Not sure, but that's the best answer I have.

The best solution is just to step over, rather than stepping into, the construction of Node.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have an unwanted breakpoint? Is the stack on the Debug view showing a `Thread[main] (Suspended...)` message? Go to the Breakpoints view, remove all of them, set it again on your Test class and try debugging again.

Check this [post](http://www.popcornfarmer.com/gamedev/2009/01/eclipse-debug-error/) (originally seen on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896882/1434089)).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not this.  I didn't have any extra breakpoints, and  I'm always careful to delete suspended threads.  Good tip to check, though.

Comment: I could have sworn that it was a breakpoint. If I set a manual breakpoint on the constructor of Throwable, I get almost your [exact stack](http://i49.tinypic.com/11jm82b.jpg)